# Filehelpers library cannot read ™ character

Tags: c#, .net, filehelpers

I am using `Filehelpers`.Net library and I have a CSV file that I am trying to read.
One of the columns has the character ™.

I am getting an error

> Line: 1054 Column: 357. No value found for the value type field:
>   'Comment' Class: 'ClientOrders'.  You must use the [FieldNullValue]
>   attribute because this is a value type and can't be null or use a
>   Nullable Type instead of the current type.

I have opened the file in Notepad++ and I can see that this invalid character is at the position the error gives.

How do I force Filehelpers to read this character?

Update:
This is my code

```
// Create a UTF-8 encoding.
UTF8Encoding utf8 = new UTF8Encoding();
var engine = new FileHelperEngine<ClientOrders>(utf8);

ClientOrders[] fileResult = engine.ReadFile(csvFile.FullName);
```

Comment: Can you share your code?

Comment: Does the "read" / "open" / whatever method that you're using take an `Encoding` object by any chance? Are you passing the right one?

Comment: I have edited my original post and added the code

Comment: And how certain are you that it actually *is* a UTF-8 file? If you open the file in a binary editor to show the exact bytes, what bytes are present at that point in the file?

Comment: Make sure that the file you are reading actually starts with the [UTF8 BOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark#UTF-8), which consists of these three hex bytes: `EF BB BF`. If not then  it could be using a different encoding.

Comment: @PeterB It could also be UTF8 without a BOM though, so those bytes not being present is not conclusive evidence that it is something else.

Comment: If Notepad opens up the file correctly and UTF8 doesn't seem to be it, I'm inclined to believe this file is probably Windows-1252 encoded instead, so what I would try (and this is still a guess, a complete shot in the dark) would be `Encoding.GetEncoding(1252)`.

Comment: Do you have code or the source of the file, know anything about this that you can share?

Answer (score 1):

Have you set the correct Encoding? I guess you want to set the encoding:

```
    // Create a UTF-8 encoding.
    UTF8Encoding utf8 = new UTF8Encoding();

    var helper = new FileHelperEngine(recordType, utf8);
```

Comment: I have added what you suggested. Same result. I also have edited my original post and added the code

Comment: You need to replace `UTF8Encoding` with the same encoding as your file. You can determine the file's encoding by opening it with Visual Studio, then _File -> Save As..._, you click the small down arrow on the Save button, and there is an option to _Save With Encoding_ that will indicate the current encoding

Comment: @shamp00 It will indicate the *guess* that Visual Studio made, it is not necessarily correct.

Comment: @shamp00 you were correct file encoding was different.